# How to extract DATE from handwritten images in python

Tags: ocr, vision-api

Extract the "Date" only from the handwritten text images without bounding the coordinates for the data in python.
The date format can be of any form e.g:

```
20-april-2019

12-02-2020

12-02-20

Feb-12-19

Feb-12-20

12Feb-2020
```

and so on

As explained in this link : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261342693_Date_Field_Extraction_in_Handwritten_Documents

Comment: Do you have sample images?

Answer (score 0):

@Nathancy
[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18J8z.jpg) for Date Extraction